# how to get UserID from Google plus Oauth2.0 for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I used Google Developers Documentation but I can't take UserID

this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:204.0f/255.0f alpha:100.0];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
```

// You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step

```
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    [signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]];
```

// Uncomment to get the user's email

```
     signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
```

// Uncomment to get the user's ID

```
     signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
    signIn.delegate = self;

    Gplusbtn = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
    Gplusbtn.frame = CGRectMake([simod CG:10], [simod CG:125], [simod CG:300], [simod CG:30]);
    Gplusbtn.style=kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide;
    Gplusbtn.enabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:Gplusbtn];
}


- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
   _signInAuthStatus.text =
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: Authentication error: %@", error];
        return;
    }
NSLog(@"ID:%@", signIn.userID);
}
```

NSLog show ID:(null)

So where code has a problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use

> [GPPSignIn sharedInstance]

like this:

```
NSString * gpUserID = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].userID;
```